# Will M2.5 screws fit the holes in the Arduino Uno?

Tags: arduino-uno, raspberrypi

I'm developing a sump pump monitor/alarm setup that will include an Arduino Uno as well as a Raspberry Pi. Both boards will be mounted to a piece of wood. The Arduino is designed to take M3 screws, but the Pi is designed to take M2.5 screws. The difference in these two screw sizes is 0.5mm (2.4mm M2.5 vs 2.9mm M3). Is this going to be close enough to be able to use the smaller M2.5 screws for both? Due to cost reasons, I want to avoid having to purchase two different sizes of screws and standoffs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the screw holes for the Arduino being the larger screw holes, the 2.9mm screws would fit, but would probably need a nut and/or a washer to properly secure things. In the end if you intend to be doing more work with Arduinos and Pis in the future that require screwing things together then just go and get proper screw sizes, you won't regret it.

Comment: Yep, that sounds like a pretty reasonable approach. I was linked to this http://www.spaenaur.com/pdf/sectionR/R11.pdf by someone else and it looks like the head of the M2.5 is sufficiently wide at 4.5mm to not fall through in any case.